# How to dynamically send variables from one function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I am new to jquery and trying to learn it by doing it. So whilst I manipulating a script, I came up with the following issue. Can someone please guide me.

It is a jquery plugin and has two files, one is a jquery plugin, and another is the direct script code, provided in the HTML. have a simple file and another file which overrides the function

Plugin file.

```
(function($){

    $.fn.animationCounter = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {

                var element = $(this);

                var defaults = {
                    start: 0,
                    end: null,
                    step: 1,
                    delay: 1000,
                    txt: "kh"
                }

                var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

                var nb_start = settings.start;
                var nb_end = settings.end;

                element.text(nb_start + settings.txt);

                var counter = function() {
                    // Definition of conditions of arrest
                    if (nb_end != null && nb_start >= nb_end) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // incrementation
                    nb_start = nb_start + settings.step;
                    // display
                    element.text(nb_start + settings.txt);
                }

                // Timer
                // Launches every "settings.delay"
                setInterval(counter, settings.delay);


        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

the code in the `<script>` tags of HTML document as follows;

```
$('.fb').animationCounter({
       start: 0,
       end: 25,
       step: 5,
       delay: 1000,
       txt: "km"
});
});
```

This plugin and function work fine.

what I want to do is following;

1. I assign different variables for the Default section (plugin file)
2. Then the Script needs to call for those data from plugin default area, and update its variables or generate variables for it.

Can someone help please or guide me how to get through of it?

Comment: didn't get what you want to do? any example will be great help to understand your requirment

Comment: Hi Yajiv, as mentioned above, I have two files, one file is the main Jquery plugin, which consits of the default variables etc. the big chunk of code which submitted at the top.<br/> the second file is a <script> which has some alternative variables and can over ride the default variables in the plugin file, and output the function <br/> i am trying to use some another function arguments to dynamically change the plugin default variables, then pass that default (changed) variables to script to store as its variables.

Comment: If you want to do it the quickest dirtiest possible way, just assign your variable to window.variablename

Comment: hi, yitzhak...would you mind giving me an example, in order for me to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript global variables to do this.

```
startValue = 500; // asign values globally.
```

then use it in your pluggin file.

```
  $.fn.animationCounter = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {

                var element = $(this);

                var defaults = {
                    start: window.startValue, // use the value
                    end: null,
                    step: 1,
                   // code continues
```

Comment: i tried this method, but could not get it right, perhaps i am missing something somewhere.

Comment: This is the main JS file code.`code`
    $('#counter-block').ready(function () {
    var mycounter = $(".counter-block");
    if (mycounter.length > 0) {
       mycounter.each(function () {
           $('.fb').animationCounter({
               start: mycounter.start,
               end: mycounter.stop,
               step: mycounter.step,
               delay: mycounter.delay,
               txt: mycounter.txt
           })
       });
    }
}(jQuery));`code`

Comment: when i put it that way, plugin out put doesn't even show at the HTML page. When i put the script with manual data as I mentioned on my problem (small code block), it works perfectly. Still could not find the missing piece to make this work.